# Generate email from Web App on iPhone

Tags: ios, html, webkit, web-applications

Ok. The question is.

We have a web app written in pure HTML & JavaScript for WebKit devices (primarily iPad).
Its main purpose is to serve people when they're offline to store a lot of structured data in the internal storage. But the application is still a pure HTML & JavaScript app. It doesn't have a native iOS app installation, it is accessed from browser.

Due to some reasons we would like to provide the users to press the button on the form and create the e-mail with the text that is stored in local browser storage, which we successfully access through JavaScript.

The data in the local storage is pure string data. It is not a binary or encoded data. But the amount is pretty large: can be around 20-30K (20-30 thousands of symbols).

Is it possible at all to make the web app to create the email and pass around all these data into email in the text form we're storing it? We would just like to be sure to provide users with alternate way of storing the data in the local queue while they're offline.

Thanks. We would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried a standard mailto URL? I see no reason why that wouldn't work, although you might run into a limitation on the size of the string (the limitation varies between browsers).

Comment: That's my main concern. I don't think the mailto will accept such large text, but we will try. A lot of browsers have a total limit of 255 chars so it might not work

Comment: I have heard that mobile safari supports up to 80,000 characters. My advice would be to test that limit and then see what happens.

Comment: @sosborn, you're completely correct. I didn't try exactly 80000 characters, but used something like 50000 and the email was correctly created. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sosborn suggested in his comments to my initial question, the mobile Safari allows much larger number of characters to be posted as a part of URL. So, the content of around 50000 characters was successfully tested and email was created without problems with the full content.

This was tested additionally for 150k text - works for both iOS and Android